# Setting up MoPub to mediate AdMob native ads

Tags: android, admob, mopub, mobile-ad-mediation

I am trying to serve AdMob ads through the MoPub SDK. So far, I did not succeed, receiving the rather unspecific error message:

> No ads found for ad unit.

- I have integrated `com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:18.3.0` and `com.mopub.mediation:admob:18.3.0.1` through Gradle
- I included my AdMob application ID in the AndroidManifest.xml
- I created an "Advanced Native Ads" unit in the AdMob dashboard
- I added AdMob as a new network in the MoPub console and inserted the ID from the AdMob "Advanced Native Ads" unit in the field for the MoPub native ad unit
- I deactivated the marketplace to only receive potential AdMob ads
- In my code, I initialize MoPub using `.withMediatedNetworkConfiguration(GooglePlayServicesAdapterConfiguration.class.getName(), config)`
- In my code, I registered a `GooglePlayServicesAdRenderer` for my `MoPubRecyclerAdapter` using a `MediaViewBinder`

What am I missing here?

In the [AdMob mediation guide](https://developers.mopub.com/publishers/mediation/networks/google/#android-1), it is also suggested to use `setLocalExtras` when requesting ads. However, this is not possible, if I use the `MoPubRecyclerAdapter`, is it?

(By the way: Is it normal that if I use the MoPub marketplace for showing native ads, I always get like only one and always the same ad? How to have more variety?)